# Check a specific time-value and give out the rest

Tags: java, methods, time

It was a bit hard to find a title for it. The following method is for a management program and it should check if a specific fly is free and **if** it is, it should print this out with the description of the flight. But Would it be possible to also tell from which to which time is the flight free (the flight can only be rented for one hour and their opening hours are from 8:00 to 20:00). So if a flight is reserved for 16:00 o'clock, means the renting ends at 17:00. Can we check this, and then say, the flight nr.1 is free from: 8:00 to 16:00 and then from 17:00 to 20:00?  The method that should this, i couldn't do much with it, as not knowing how and what is called. Any small help is appreciated.

The method:

```
public static void avilable(int[] flightQuantity, String[] name, String[] description) {
            for (int i = 0; i < flugAnzahl.length; i++) {
                if (vorname[i] == null) {
                    System.out.println("The flight with the description: " + bezeichnung[i] + " is free");
                }
            }
```

The method where a flight can be booked/rented:

```
public static void flugBuchen(int[] flugAnzahl, String[] bezeichnung, int[] zeit, int index, String[] vorname, String[] nachname) throws ParseException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String h = "";
        System.out.println("Welchen Flug möchten Sie buchen (Geben Sie bitte die Nummer dieses ein)");
        index = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < bezeichnung.length; i++) {
            if (index == i) {
                System.out.println("Geben Sie den Vornamen dieser Person ein: ");
                vorname[i] = sc.nextLine();
                sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Geben Sie den Nachnamen dieser Person ein: ");
                nachname[i] = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Für wann wird der Flug gebucht: (hh:mm)");
                int zeit2 = sc.nextInt();
                zeit[i] += zeit2;
                while (zeit[i] > 8 || zeit[i] < 20) {
                    System.out.println("Geben Sie eine Zeit zwischen 8 und 20 ein: ");
                    zeit[i] = sc.nextInt();
                }
                SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't ask for a time and check if the flight is free to be booked. Offer only free slots. It is very unlikely to be able to book flights freely for for example 16:34. I'd expect to be offered flights going from place a to b at for example, 10:00, 11:00 , 13:00, 14:00, 15:00 and so on.

Comment: BTW, `int` is not really ideal for hh:mm ...

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Yes, you can check that. --- Now read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: Well, I haven't started the question with "is it possible… ". I am not expecting anyone to offer much of their time for me. Why not help each other, if someone has experience and can give a little hint?

Comment: Es tut mir leid, I find this question quite a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. If I were to give you a good answer, I would be doing your data modelling work for you. It’s not in scope for Stack Overflow. One tip, though: [Anti-pattern: parallel collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/).

Comment: thanks man @OleV.V.